# How i can map this object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, dictionary, object

I have some problems when mapping an object:

```
const questions = [
  {
    id:1,
    questionText: 'W którym roku firma apple wprowadziła do sprzedaży pierwszy komputer?',
    answerOptions: [
      { id: 1, answerText: 'A.1974', isCorrect: false, result: [] },
      { id: 2, answerText: 'B.1976', isCorrect: true, result: (correctAnswer) },
      { id: 3, answerText: 'C.1984', isCorrect: false, result: [] },
      { id: 4, answerText: 'D.1990', isCorrect: false, result: [] },
    ],
  }
]
```

How i can map object like this one?

I did something like this, but next i got problems with (`.answerOptions` is `undefined`), when i tried to change my array to another array (splice draggable in DND)

```
Questions[currentQuestion].answerOptions.map(
  ({ id, answerText, isCorrect, result }, index) => {
    return (
      <Draggable
        key={`draggable2-${id}`}
        draggableId={`draggable2-${id}`}
        index={index}
      >
        {(provided, snapshot) => {
          return (
            <div
              ref={provided.innerRef}
              {...provided.draggableProps}
              {...provided.dragHandleProps}
            >
              <div
                className="answer"
                onClick={() => handleAnswerClick(isCorrect)}
              >
                <div className="answerText">{answerText}</div>
                <div className={resultCorrect}>{result}</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          );
        }}
      </Draggable>
    );
  }
)
```

Comment: is `Questions[currentQuestion]` (with capital "Q") correct? In the previous snippet you wrote `const questions = ...` (with small "q").

Answer (score 1):

I think you should make `questions` lowercase

```
questions[currentQuestion].answerOptions.map(
```

additionally for future to be sure that `questions[currentQuestion]` exist you can add questionmarks after so you will not have errors with undefined:

```
questions[currentQuestion]?.answerOptions?.map(
```

Comment: Just a side note / unsolicited opinion on the use of the optional chaining (`?.`): IMVHO it should be used very cautiously otherwise it risks to become "a crutch", hiding issues that might not cause the code to stop running but can still prevent it from working as expected. In other words, the optional chaining should not be carelessly used when you _do not know_ whether something will be defined or not; it should be used because you _know_ that something can be undefined.